# Keras NoneTypeError in deep auto-encoder-decoder structure / Shape error

Tags: machine-learning, keras, nlp

I have trouble making my neural network train. I have defined the neural network as follows:

```
shared = embedding_layer

inputA = keras.Input(shape=(40, ), name="anchor")  # Variable-length sequence of ints
inputP = keras.Input(shape=(40, ), name="positive")  # Variable-length sequence of ints
inputN = keras.Input(shape=(40, ), name="negative")  # Binary vectors of size num_tags

concatenated = layers.concatenate([inputA, inputP, inputN])

embedded_A = shared(concatenated)

encoded = Dense(900, activation = "relu")(embedded_A)
encoded = Dense(600, activation = "relu")(encoded)
encoded = Dense(300, activation = "relu")(encoded)
encoded = Dense(100, activation = "relu")(encoded)

decoded = Dense(100, activation = "relu")(encoded)
decoded = Dense(300, activation = "relu")(decoded)
decoded = Dense(600, activation = "relu")(decoded)
decoded = Dense(900, activation = "relu")(decoded)


predictionsA = Dense(40, activation="sigmoid", name ='outA')(decoded)
predictionsP = Dense(40, activation="sigmoid", name ='outB')(decoded)
predictionsN = Dense(40, activation="sigmoid", name ='outC')(decoded)

ml_model = keras.Model(
    inputs=[inputA, inputP, inputN],
    outputs=[predictionsA, predictionsP, predictionsN]
)


ml_model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mse'
)

ml_model.fit(
    {"anchor": anchor, "positive": positive, "negative": negative},
    {"outA": anchor, "outB": positive, 'outC': negative},
    epochs=2)
```

Which schematically looks like [image]

The embeddingment layer is defined as follows:

```
embedding_m = model.syn0
embedding_layer = Embedding(len(vocab),
                            300,
                            weights=[embedding_m],
                            input_length=40,
                            trainable=True)
```

```
What I feed into the network is three numpy arrays of shape (120000, 40) which look like this:


array([[   2334,   23764,    7590, ..., 3000001, 3000001, 3000001],
       [3000000,    1245,    1124, ..., 3000001, 3000001, 3000001],
       [    481,     491,    5202, ..., 3000001, 3000001, 3000001],
       ...,
       [3000000,     125,   20755, ..., 3000001, 3000001, 3000001],
       [1217971,  168575,     239, ...,    9383,    1039,   87315],
       [  12990,      91,  258231, ..., 3000001, 3000001, 3000001]])
```

And the input is the same as the output, as I am making an auto-encoder decoder.

The error I get is:

Dimensions must be equal, but are 120 and 32 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](model_3/outA/Sigmoid, mean_squared_error/Cast)' with input shapes: [32,120,40], [32,40].

But I can't seem to find out why, or how to fix it... Any ideas? I can provide more examples if needed. I suspect that there is some dimension error, as I would ideally like my output to be of shape (120000,40) exactly as my input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed version of the problematic endcoder - decoder:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.layers import Dense

#shared = embedding_layer
#Simulate that...
shared=Dense(1,activation="relu")

inputA = keras.Input(shape=(40, ), name="anchor")  # Variable-length sequence of ints
inputP = keras.Input(shape=(40, ), name="positive")  # Variable-length sequence of ints
inputN = keras.Input(shape=(40, ), name="negative")  # Binary vectors of size num_tags

concatenated = layers.concatenate([inputA, inputP, inputN])

embedded_A = shared(concatenated)

encoded = Dense(900, activation = "relu")(embedded_A)
encoded = Dense(600, activation = "relu")(encoded)
encoded = Dense(300, activation = "relu")(encoded)
encoded = Dense(100, activation = "relu")(encoded)

#decoded = Dense(100, activation = "relu")(encoded)
decoded = Dense(300, activation = "relu")(encoded)
decoded = Dense(600, activation = "relu")(decoded)
decoded = Dense(900, activation = "relu")(decoded)


predictionsA = Dense(40, activation="sigmoid", name ='outA')(decoded)
predictionsP = Dense(40, activation="sigmoid", name ='outB')(decoded)
predictionsN = Dense(40, activation="sigmoid", name ='outC')(decoded)

ml_model = keras.Model(
    inputs=[inputA, inputP, inputN],
    outputs=[predictionsA, predictionsP, predictionsN]
)


ml_model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mse'
)

#Simulate...
anchor=tf.random.uniform((100,40))
positive=tf.random.uniform((100,40))
negative=tf.random.uniform((100,40))

ml_model.fit(
    {"anchor": anchor, "positive": positive, "negative": negative},
    {"outA": anchor, "outB": positive, 'outC': negative},
    epochs=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the one "decoded" row to fix your network structure:

[image]

Comment: Change also in row 24 the last part as encoded. I'll add the working code to you as an answer!

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thanks a lot. The new problem is that it only runs for one iteration of my sentences, so my output weights from the last output nodes are (300,40), and sadly not (120000, 300, 40) as I would expect for all my sentences. Should I put it in a loop?